# Can I record the output of an <audio> without use of the microphone?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc, html5-audio

I have an `<audio>` element and I'm changing the speed, start/end bounds, and pitch. I want to see if it's possible to record the audio I hear in the browser. However I don't want to just record with the microphone because of the lower quality.

I could do the same effects server-side but I'd rather not since I'd be basically duplicating the same functionality with two different technologies.

---

In response to a flag vote since it's "unclear what I'm asking", I'll rephrase.

I have an `<audio>` element playing on the page. I have some javascript manipulating the play-rate, volume, etc. I then want my *browser* to record the audio *as I hear it*. This is not the microphone. I want to create a new audio file that is as close as possible to the one playing. If it's at 75%, then the new file will be at 75% volume.

Comment: You can perhaps use the `captureStream()` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream

Comment: Yes in supported browsers, use the `MediaElement.captureStream()`  method along with the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). But note that these technologies are still in active development and that current implementations are still full of bugs. E.g, for your case, current stable FF will stop the rendering of the original media audio if you change its volume while recording...

Comment: If you need support for older browsers, you can also just pass your MediaElement to the WebAudio API thanks to the [`createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) method. From there, you'll be able to fetch the raw PCM data of your media and to save it (note that volume controls should be done on the webAudioApi itself though).

Comment: Any chance one of yall can give an example of how to record an `<audio>` tag? I'm looking at those docs, but not connecting the dots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In supporting browsers, you could use the [`MediaElement.captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream) method along with the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

But note that these technologies are still in active development and that current implementations are still full of bugs.
E.g, for your case, current stable FF will stop the rendering of the original media audio if you change its volume while recording... I didn't had time to search for a bug report on it, but anyway, this is just one of the many bugs you'll find.

```js
// here we will save all the chunks of our record
const chunks = [];
// wait for the original media is ready
audio.oncanplay = function() {
  audio.volume = 0.5; // just for your example
  // FF still does prefix this unstable method
  var stream = audio.captureStream ? audio.captureStream() : audio.mozCaptureStream();
  // create a MediaRecorder from our stream
  var rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  // every time we've got a bit of data, store it
  rec.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
  // once everything is done
  rec.onstop = e => {
    audio.pause();
    // concatenate our chunks into one file
    let final = new Blob(chunks);
    let a = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(final));
    a.controls = true;
    document.body.append(a);
  };
  rec.start();
  // record for 6 seconds
  setTimeout(() => rec.stop(), 6000);
  // for demo, change volume at half-time
  setTimeout(() => audio.volume = 1, 3000);
};

// FF will "taint" the stream, even if the media is served with correct CORS...
fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3").then(resp => resp.blob()).then(b => audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(b));
```

```html
<audio id="audio" autoplay controls></audio>
```

For older browsers, you could use the WebAudio API's [`createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) method, to pass your audio element media through the API.
From there, you'd be able to extract raw PCM data to arrayBuffers and save it.

In following demo, I'll use [`recorder.js`](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/dist/recorder.js) library which does *greatly* help for the extraction + save to wav process.

```js
audio.oncanplay = function(){
  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

  gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;

  source.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);  

  var rec = new Recorder(gainNode);

   rec.record();
  setTimeout(function(){
    gainNode.gain.value = 1;
    }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    rec.stop()
    audio.pause();
    rec.exportWAV(function(blob){
      var a = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      a.controls = true;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      });
    }, 6000);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/master/dist/recorder.js"></script>
<audio id="audio" crossOrigin="anonymous" controls src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

Comment: working through this. But I see what you mean about being experimental, I had to enable `Experimental Web Platform Features` in chrome://flags to get `captureStream` defined.

Answer (score 3):

As Kaiido mentions in his answer, `captureStream()` is one way of doing it. However, that is not fully supported in Chrome and Firefox yet. MediaRecorder does also not allow for track set changes during a recording, and a MediaStream coming from `captureStream()` might have those (depends on the application) - thus ending the recording prematurely.

If you need a supported way of recording *only audio* from a media element, you can use a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`, pipe that to a `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`, and pipe the `stream` attribute of that to MediaRecorder.

Here's an example you can use on a page with an existing audio element:

```
const a = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
const ac = new AudioContext();
const source = ac.createMediaElementSource(a);

// The media element source stops audio playout of the audio element.
// Hook it up to speakers again.
source.connect(ac.destination);

// Hook up the audio element to a MediaStream.
const dest = ac.createMediaStreamDestination();
source.connect(dest);

// Record 10s of audio with MediaRecorder.
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(dest.stream);
recorder.start();
recorder.ondataavailable = ev => {
  console.info("Finished recording. Got blob:", ev.data);
  a.src = URL.createObjectURL(ev.data);
  a.play();
};
setTimeout(() => recorder.stop(), 10 * 1000);
```

Note that neither approach works with cross-origin audio sources without a proper CORS setup, as both WebAudio and recordings would give the application the possibility to inspect audio data.

Comment: Reading the question again, I see that you want to record with different playback rates and pitch settings.

Comment: Sorry, mistyped comment. Continues: The MediaElementAudioSourceNode doesn't explicitly mention those (hence forwarding them is supported by the spec), but at least Firefox does not properly forward playbackRate. I'd say it's a matter of time until that is supported. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=966247