# How to record web/browser audio output (not microphone audio)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, mp3, web-audio-api

Has anyone successfully been able to access the audio stream that is being outputted from the browser window (not from the microphone)?

We are currently building a sound studio app where the user can play an instrument and we want to be able to record and save that audio as it is being generated. We have real-time audio output being generated by locally saved mp3 files (i.e. on pressing piano keys), but have no way of capturing this audio stream sequence to save it.

Comment: You can find your answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336604/can-i-record-the-output-of-an-audio-without-use-of-the-microphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using the Web Audio API for this project.

First, you need to create a [MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode).  This is a Web Audio node that you can connect the rest of your graph to, and have it output to a MediaStream which can be recorded.

```
const mediaStreamDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

yourSourceNode.connect(mediaStreamDestination);
```

Next, you need a MediaRecorder which will take the raw PCM audio as the MediaStream produces it, and encode it with the desired codec.

```
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamDestination.stream);

mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (e) => {
  // Recorded data is in `e.data`
});

mediaREcorder.start();
```

Note that this MediaRecorder example is the exact same, no matter whether your MediaStream is sourced from getUserMedia, or from your Web Audio API graph.

Full example here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode

Comment: Im trying to implement this in angular. Can you explain what exactly is "someOtherNode"?

Comment: @NotABot `someOtherNode` in this case is the source of the audio.  I've updated the name of that node in the answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to record audio if we are not aware of audio source? In my case Im using 3rd party SDK which outputs audio internally.

Comment: @NotABot What specifically do you mean by, "outputs audio internally"?  Which SDK?

Comment: The audio is played by SDK which is blackbox for us. Currently Im thinking to use pulseaudio for that